# joomla 1.5 Custom mobile framework not loading css

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, migration

Hi Guys I have been tasked with moving a custom framework from joomla 1.5 to 3.0 I have gotten the framework to load the homepage perfectly however when I go to other pages the css wont load here is the code:

PHP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl(); ?     >templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl(); ?>templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/addons.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/typo.css" type="text/css" />
```

HTML Output:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/addons.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/typo.css" type="text/css" />



<!-- CSS for handheld devices -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/handheld/layout.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flyvail/index.php/templates/FlyVail2/css/handheld/template.css" type="text/css" />


<!-- CSS for handheld devices -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/handheld/layout.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->templateurl(); ?>/css/handheld/template.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- //CSS for handheld devices -->
```

I am not sure why it isn't loading right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in your template's index.php file, then try:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template . '/css/NAMEOFSTYLESHEET.css', $type = 'text/css', $media = 'screen,projection');
```

to add your style sheets instead.

My guess is that `$this->baseurl()` does not work with the `()` as it is a parameter, not a function.  As such, your link is shown without the baseurl is generated by a relative link which also takes into account the base href that joomla sets.  This means when you are not in the root of the site, it the link is wrong.

(Your code would probably work if you just removed all the ()s, but the addStyleSheet method is better practise)

If that doesn't work, can you take a look to see if the URL generated is different on your homepage where you say it works and the sub-page where you say it does not, and add this additional info to your question.